# Nullspace and column space

Tags: linear-algebra

In my introductory Linear Algebra course, we are studying orthogonality. The tutor was explaining to one of the students that if a vector is in the column space of a symmetric matrix that contains elements from the main diagonal of the matrix, then to verify that this indeed is the vector of the column space, we take the perpendicularity of this vector and see that the null space of the matrix is the subset of this perpendicular vector.

The tutor left before I could ask him how this could be done or is possible. I was wondering if someone could either explain or direct me towards some article that discusses this. The text we are reading is Linear Algebra by Strang but I couldn't find the section where he talks about this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "perpendicularity" although I suspect that it's another term for the [orthogonal complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) (am I right?). If that's the case, then this is simply a consequence of the fact that the rowspace is the orthogonal complement of the nullspace. For symmetric matrices, the rowspace and the columnspace are equal, so this applies to columnspaces of symmetric matrices too.